# Is there a reason why session would be undefined?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Hello and thanks in advance for taking a look at this issue. I am using nextAuth for authentication and would like to show pages based on user authentication. Upon running this code below, it returns 'undefined' for session. However, I followed the docs provided by nextAuth, and don't see any reason why the session would be 'undefined'. Can you help debug?

````
import Head from 'next/head';
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import Dashboard from './dashboard';

export default function Home({ session }) {
  console.log('SESS', session);           //returned 'undefined'

  if (!session) {
    return (
      <div className="">
        <Head>
          <title>Some Title</title>
          <meta
            name="description"
            content=""
          />
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>
        <div className="">
          <main className="bg-gradient-to-r from-gray-50 via-slate-300 to-gray-50 pb-6">
            <div> This shows if there is no session </div>
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <Dashboard />;
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context);

   console.log(session)    // logs out session successfully.

  return {
    props: {
      session,
    },
  };
}```
````

Comment: Did you wrap `<Component {...pageProps} />` with `<SessionProvider session={session}>` in `pages/_app.js`?

Comment: @MarkG - Yes I did. The behavior is weird cos I am able to get the session inside of the getServerSideProps(), but not when I pass it down to the Home component.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?